# Show ProgressDialog while loading data and return view

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have Fragment that loads data from web and shows them

so basically the root view is based on web data and cannot be shown until data is loaded

so what i'm trying to do is to show ProgressDialog while the data is loaded

my code :

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    URL url = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;
    int responseCode = 0;
    try {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo, container, false);
        rootView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        url = new URL(getString(R.string.url)+"/todo.php");
        urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // ADD DATA TO ROOT VIEW
        }
        return rootView;
    }catch...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you problem correctly, then you want to display progress in a Progressbar.
First of all, add a progressbar to your layout or add it programmatically (with an id as well). Then find it in the code via findViewById.

Now you can basically do:

```
try {
        ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(this); // findViewById instead!
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("www.google.com").openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String str;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // here you can set an indeterminate progress bar for example
            pb.setIndeterminate(true);
            Log.d("log", str);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But you should consider doing this in the background (for example with an AsyncTask), because otherwise it would be bad practice and it could stall User Interaction, because of the Main/UI Thread being clotted already.

Here is a [good example](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Sending-and-Managing-Network-Requests) of the things you want to achieve.